# Some duplicate enum type casting in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, typecasting-operator, typecast-operator

See the codes below:

```swift
enum Gender {
  case Male, Female, Unknown
}
enum ExplicitGender {
  case Male, Female
}

func whatGender(_ g: Gender) {
  print("I am \(g)")
}

func makeSureYourGender() -> ExplicitGender {
  return ExplicitGender.Male
}

var myGender = makeSureYourGender();

// How to Cast type `ExplicitGender` to `Gender`?
// This fails
// whatGender(myGender)
```

The syntax `myGender as ExplicitGender` is not correct.

Actually, the `Male`,`Female` in `ExplicitGender` and `Gender` are the same.
Make the 2 is 2 different Enum Types is not exactly correct.

Or There is another code structure or syntax to resolve this problem?

See also:

```swift
enum Language {
  case English, French, Arabic, Russian, Chinese, Spanish, Japanese, German, Italian
}

enum UNOfficialLanguage {
  case English, French, Arabic, Russian, Chinese, Spanish
}
```

In **typescript**, i will do it with:

```js
type UNOfficialLanguage = 'English' | 'French' | 'Arabic' | 'Russian' | 'Chinese' | 'Spanish';
type Language = UNOfficialLanguage | 'Japanese' | 'German' | 'Italian';
```

Comment: Why have two almost identical enums in the first place? Sounds like you just need `typealias Gender = ExplicitGender?`. Now gender can be `.none`, `.some(.Male)` or `.some(.Female)`.

Comment: apologize, This example is not representative enough.

Comment: Then please show a more representative example.

Comment: Now I don't see why these should be two different types. Are you sure you want this distinction on the type level? Anyway, enums don't do that in Swift. One workaround is to use classes with `static let` properties and inheritance.

Comment: On the type level, it will cause code intelligence that make the code easy to use. `class` and inheritance is fine, but the properties should be assigned a value, it looks like the code is redundant.

Comment: I considered the type and value level issues. I think that all (build time for coder, enums, runtime for app user)clear and enumerable content (such as language) should be defined at the type level, so that not only application users can quickly choose, and use it as code Can also be programmed quickly by code intelligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TypeScript example is not an enum. It's a union of string literal types. There is no equivalent to literal types in Swift. (TypeScript also has enums, but they're a different thing.)

Swift and TypeScript have radically different approaches to what it means to be a type. In TypeScript, two things that have the same structure are the same type ("structural typing"). In Swift, two things can have the same structure can be unrelated and what matters is the name of the type ("nominal typing"). The TS way is convenient, but there are many types it cannot express. The Swift way can express more things, but it lacks certain conveniences.

For example, in TypeScript, if you declare two interfaces with the same properties, they are interchangeable:

```
interface Animal {
  legs: number;
}

interface AirTravel {
  legs: number;
}

let trip: AirTravel = {legs: 4};

function feedAnimal(a: Animal) {}

feedAnimal(trip)  // No problem... legs are legs
```

The equivalent code in Swift will give an error:

```
struct Animal {
  var legs: Int
}

struct AirTravel {
  var legs: Int
}

let trip = AirTravel(legs: 4)

func feedAnimal(_ a: Animal) {}

feedAnimal(trip)
// error: cannot convert value of type 'AirTravel' to expected argument type 'Animal'
```

Whether you think one approach is better typically depends on the problems you're trying to solve. (I find the Swift approach dramatically more powerful than the TypeScript approach. Others find Swift restrictive because it won't let you do things you "know" are correct unless you can prove to the compiler it's correct.)

To your example, just because two symbols have the same spelling (`Language.English` and `UNOfficialLanguage.English`) doesn't mean they are related in any way. If you want to convert between them, you'll need to convert between them.

That said, Swift does have conveniences to convert to strings and from strings.

```
enum Language: String {
  case english, french, arabic, russian, chinese, spanish, japanese, german, italian
}

enum UNOfficialLanguage: String {
  case english, french, arabic, russian, chinese, spanish
}
```

Note the addition of `: String`. This allows you to convert easily between the enum and a string representation of the enum.

```
let l = UNOfficialLanguage.arabic
let language = Language(rawValue: l.rawValue) // type is Language?
```

Note that `language` is of type `Language?` since this conversion could fail. Since you happen to know that Language is a superset of UNOfficialLanguage, you could force the conversion in that direction:

```
extension Language {
    init(_ official: UNOfficialLanguage) {
        self.init(rawValue: official.rawValue)!
    }
}

let language = Language(l) // type is Language
```

For more on this feature, see [Raw Values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID149) in the Swift Programming Language.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I have already paid attention to the usage of `: String` in the *swift* documentation. This seems to be the best way to solve this type of problem. In fact, what I hope is that not only can there be selective input when facing the application user, but also when the code is used by developers, there can also be code intelligence to provide them with options.

Comment: For example, there is a `Direction` enumeration containing `up`,`down`,`left`,`right`,`forward`,`backward`. In some scenes, all these directions are needed, such as an object moves in a space freely `freeMove(dir: Direction)`, in other scenarios, only `forward`, `backward` are needed, for example, when this object is restricted in moving in a narrow passage, `straightMove(dir: ForwardBackDirection)`, which `ForwardBackDirection` only contains `forward` and `backward`, but the two options and `forward`/`backward` in `Direction` should essentially be descriptions of the same characteristics.

Comment: I hope that developers are restricted to only pass in `forward` and `backward` (code intelligence) when calling the `straightMove` method, instead of using `if (dir !='forward' ) || dir !='backward') throw error ...` like traditional `javascript` to solve the problem.
In `typescript`, my solution is to use `string literal types`. Strings are comparable. At the type level, operators such as `|`, `Exclude<T>` can also be used, which is easy to solve. The problem is that it is very friendly to developers, and this feature is not available in many programming languages.

Comment: If such a feature were added to Swift, it would likely be in the form of GADTs. https://forums.swift.org/t/generalized-abstract-data-types-gadts/42298 The team is interested in the feature, but I don't believe it's made it to any of the roadmaps. (It wouldn't be implemented as string literals, though. They'd still be enum cases. TS-style literals-as-types doesn't make sense in Swift since it breaks structural typing.)

Comment: There is a class `Shape`, and 2 instances `circle`, `rectangle`. And I make a function `drawShape(shape: Shape)`, it means any instance of `Shape` can be the argument of `drawShape()`, Logically it's right, because instances of `Shape` is infinite. Otherwise in some condition, or use case of a library, there only needs 2 `Shape` s, that's why I want the argument of `drawShape()` to be enumerable for users. Should a grammar like `drawShape(shape: Shape in ShapeEnum){...} enum ShapeEnum { case circle, rectangle }`(the cases in enum should be the same signature of class instances) to be added?

Comment: No, that's definitely not how it would be done in Swift. First, Shape would not be a class; it would be a protocol or struct. There would be a protocol `Drawable` and `drawShape` would accept a `Drawable`. Types can conform to `Drawable`. The missing feature is that you cannot currently conform specific enum values to a protocol, and you cannot parameterize types with values (you cannot have a `Shape<Sides=4>` type). Those are all possible and useful additions.

Comment: **cannot parameterize types with values**, Yes, This is the crux of the problem. What I'm thinking of is, in the actual world, there is no **types**, all the things you see/feel/touch...such as a table, a cup of coffee... are all **values**, **types** is just a abstract expression for describing the all these.

Comment: Meanwhile, **Language** takes the role of **parameterize types with values**, When I say "I need a cup of coffee", I am using the value `a cup of coffee` to describe the type `coffee`, and then the staff of Starbucks hear it, and abstracted what heard to the type `Coffee`, and asked "Latte or Mocha?", she is trying to `extends` or `instantiates` the type.

Comment: From another perspective, When I entered the Starbucks, I was given a list of coffee they offer, (all the texts of coffee they passed to me are **values that parameterize types**), and I ask for a "Mocha", the staff got my **values** and transform it to **type**, and then "instantiates" it.

Comment: Sorry for my crazy thinking

Comment: Some advantage by coding with JavaScript is Type insensitive, I can create a dictionary with the keys of a string enumeration, values in different types, is there any way to achieve this scenario in swift?

Comment: In typescript, I will create an interface or type instead of dictionary, and reach the enumeration of keys by **keyof** operator. Now I can index types.

Answer (score 2):

You can not (Downcast or Upcast) cast objects that are not related to each other. Please check [casting on swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html) for information on how to cast.

Gender and ExplicitGender are enums which are not related to each other.

One solution is to create a helper function which converts Gender types to ExplicitGender types and vice versa. Please see the below code as an example:

```
func genderFromExplicitGender(gender: ExplicitGender) -> Gender {
  switch gender {
   case .Male: return .Male
   case .Female: return .Female
 }
return .Unknown }
```

The catch here is even though Gender and Explicit gender have Male and Female. They are not related to each other in anyway. The code above checked for Male (as ExplicitGender.Male) and returns Male (as Gender.Male), does the same for Female.

I will advise you read more on casting in swift